# my magento website can‘t use email function, maybe it is about the vps email setting? anyone can help me?

Tags: email, vps, magento-1.6

i'm running a new store on magento, the contact us show successfully sent email to me, but i didn't get any email. i'm using google email address, but for the vps setting i'm not sure how to set up it. as i'm using linux vps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using personal VPS hosting, you have to install email server or ask support to do that. The most popular one for Linux is Postfix. You can find a lot of information how to install postfix depend on Linux distrubution. I recommend you to install postfix and use mysql to configure such settings like email forwarding, user list, etc.